# How to parent animated object to animated object

Tags: animation, parent, axis

[image]

I want to show bond 2 rotating and the bond 1 also rotating. 
So basically parenting 1 to 2 is what I want to do. But when I animate in a particular axis using local axis it is rotating in all axis. How can I solve this ?

Comment: so basically you want to animate the rotation in local space

Comment: I'm not sure I'm totally following you. What tool are you using to rotate? Are you using the axis shortcut keys? For instance, the cylinder you have selected in the image, you would press R to enter rotate mode and then press Y to restrict the rotation to the Y axis. Without restricting to a certain axis, the rotation will appear to be rotating like you are in global orientation.

Comment: Make sure your local axes are oriented orthogonally to the objects. You might have rotated the meshes in edit mode, meaning that the local axis of each object is not where you need it.

Comment: the origin of each segment must be on its rotation axis, then parent each segment to its parent, and use RXX to rotate (or RYY, RZZ). You can also parent each segment to an empty, it can be convenient.